# How to get/set current volume level in Xamarin froms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How to get device's current volume level and use that inside our application play sound? Also how to get notified about sound level changed by hardware button or software seekbar?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms doesn't have Audio API's yet, so you will need to implement the functionality for each platform on your own. However, there seems to be a library called Xamarin Audio Manager and it should do at least some of the things that you require, take a look at it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/jcphlux/XamarinAudioManager).

You can then use the project as a good starting point for extending it to meet all your needs. Audio API's in both Android and iOS are relatively easy to understand.